# SWRevealViewController from the right side on swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController library to make a slide out menu in swift, but I am struggling to put this menu in the right side. I have seen on the library description this comment

```
// Optional right view controller, can be nil if not used
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *rightViewController;
```

but I am not familiar with objective C and I am not being able to do this on swift. This is a part of my code for the default(left) menu:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var playlistOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playlistOutlet.target = self.revealViewController()
    playlistOutlet.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

}
}
```

And revealViewController is called from the SWRevealViewController library

Comment: Add more code to your question. What is playlistOutlet? How do you declare revealViewController?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I followed this solution, in the controller of the front siding view use this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        favoritesButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        favoritesButton.action = "rightRevealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```

Don't forget to create the Outlet to the item bar button first. In the storyboard, set the segue value to sw_right

[image: Xcode 7 Beta 6 Screenshot]

And first that didn't work for me, but a clean helped.

Comment: Thank you very much, in my case I added sw_rear & sw_right to support both languages ( English & Arabic )

Comment: @BackPacker how did you added both by storyboard or by code, can you show me please

Answer (score 7):

> Swift 3

### Add this code to yourViewController

```
if revealViewController() != nil{
        sideMenuBtn.target = revealViewController()
        sideMenuBtn.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

---

### at MainStoryBoard

Set the segue identifier value to **sw_right** instead of **sw_rear**

- Worked for me

Better Alternative: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Comment: Set the segue identifier value to sw_right instead of sw_rear => Worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: I Have a problem, I want to control the opening of the side menu according to a condition , when condition is true open on left , and when false open on right , how can we set this independently from using the storyboard segues

Comment: @MhmdRizk you can make two view controllers in the main story board or two separated main story boards
and load the one that fit your needs
but If I were you, I'd make it programmatically better

Comment: @MhmdRizk were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @AshishSharma no, I simply stoped using SWReveal, and I recommend you too to stop using it.
and this is a great alternative that is better more customizable :
https://github.com/teodorpatras/SideMenuController

Comment: @MhmdRizk okay, for anyone else looking at this solution please look at my answer below.

Comment: This is a great solution: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu. Thanks @MamdouhElNakeeb

Answer (score 6):

Can you try this code:

```
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var sidemenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sideMenu") as! SideMenuViewController
    sidemenuViewController.delegate = self
    revealViewController().rightViewController = sidemenuViewController
    revealViewController().delegate = self
    sideMenuItem.target = self.revealViewController()
    self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.width * 0.8
    sideMenuItem.action = Selector("rightRevealToggle:")
```

Comment: actually I am having many bugs, like in the second line -Used of undeclared type 'SideMenuViewController'. In the 5th line -Can not assign a value of type 'ViewController' to value of type 'SWRevealViewControllerDelegate'...

Comment: You should import SWRevealViewControllerDelegate first of all. Are you using Storyboard?

Comment: yes I am using Storyboard. And I think I found a solution. In the Storyboard Segue Identifier I am adding sw_right and than I am changing this line playlistOutlet.action = Selector("rightRevealToggle:") but now I am not being able to see the full width of the menu, because the left side of the menu is hided from the main view. Is there a way to move the menu in the right side ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and tried the code in my project. It works now.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you so much @ridvankucuk but again I am having a problem. I am pasting your code implementing SWRevealViewControllerDelegate in the main ViewController and than in second line I am implementing the var as TableViewController, but in third line I am having an error saying 'TableViewController' dose not have a member named 'delegate'

Comment: You can delete that line from your code.  Do you get any other error?

Comment: Now I am not having errors before building, but when I am running the app it is crashing with an error 'libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)' and it is pointing at the AppDelegate class

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1**

```
private func setRightMenu(){
    btnMenuright.addTarget(revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}
```

I tried to do this when you want the sw_right show up. this code It worked for me

Comment: i am getting nil object and can not call rightRevealToggle function, i want to add RightMenu under the navigation pushed viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

**For menu from right side,**

menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))

**For those who are looking for localization and support for RTL/LTR Languages.**

All you need to do is, when you create a new localization file, select the option "**Interface builder Storyboard**" instead of "**Localizable string**". It will create another storyboard for that language, and it's okay to do this cuz as far as I know, you'll use it only for Arabic language.

Now in the new storyboard rename the segue to "**sw_right**" and in the old one let it be "**sw_rear**".

When in your **viewDidLoad()** for the menu button, simply check for the current locale language

`let language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]` , and open menu from either side depending on your choice.

This is my piece of code:

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {

            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()

            let language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]

            if language == "ar-AE" || language == "ar-US" || (language.range(of: "ar-") != nil) {
                menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
            }
            else {
                menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            }

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        }
```

You may also use the region code as I've noticed that the user may change language or the region individually.

```
let region = NSLocale.current.regionCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 *override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
.
.
.
 menuButton.addTarget(revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  if revealViewController() != nil {
   revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = 200 //any number
   view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()
   view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }
}
```

in the main story board add a segue of type "custom" from SWRevealViewController to ur sideMenuViewController
then select the segue and in the inspector set its identifier to `sw_right`
and class to `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` 
that's all.**