# How to change SWReaveal side menu form left to right when change language from (English to Arabic)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift4, swrevealviewcontroller

i'm trying to translate application from English to Arabic so i go to info in application and add Arabic , 
this add to file with storyboard when i change on it, it's appear right in application but the problem the side menu not open from right 
so any help
and this is my code for side menu

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
}
```

i need help to let side menu appear from right when language Arabic and left when language  English

Comment: Do you want to change it by programmatically?

Comment: i want it work when language change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is Working Code**

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // Here menuViewController is SideDrawer ViewCOntroller
    if let sidemenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuViewController") as? menuViewController{
        revealViewController().rightViewController = sidemenuViewController
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.width * 0.8
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
    }
}
```

By Storyboard you can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32501968/10150796)